# How would I open a manpage in GridView by clicking on a WinForms button?

Tags: winforms, powershell, gridview, scope

I am trying to open up a manpage (Get-Help alias) when I click on a button using Powershell and WinForms.

I have a text box that allows you to input a cmdlet or help topic and when you press a button, it should open up the manpage documentation in GridView. Currently, it opens the GridView and grabs the correct help docs but something messes up along the way and I think it has to do with interpretation before it is passed off to GridView.

Here is what I have:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$input = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$input.Size = '100,20'
$input.Location = '10,20'

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Size = '100,20'
$button.Location = '10,60'
$button.Add_Click({
    Invoke-Expression ("man " + ($global:input.Text)) | Out-GridView
    })

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($input, $button)

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})

$form.ShowDialog()
```

What happens is the GridView opens but the title shows `Invoke-Expression ("man " + ($input.Text)) | Out-GridView` and the contents are the generic default information for manpages.

I tried to attach the `Invoke-Expression` to a variable and then pipe the variable out to GridView. I tried to set `(Get-Help ($input.Text))` to a variable and then pipe it to GridView. I even tried to initialize the `$input.Text` property by putting `$input.Text = ''` just after the `$input.Location` property.

I really think its how the Powershell engine is interpreting the expression but I don't know how to tell it to work the way I am wanting it to.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT**: Ok, I just realized something. I think the $input.Text property is not getting populated correctly.

What I did was added `[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($input.Text)` in the `Click` event for `$button` and commented out the `Invoke-Expression`. What it should do is open a message box and place within it what is typed in the text box (`$input.Text`). The message box is blank. I'm thinking that it may have to do with scoping but the `$input.Text` should be `$global` and accessible from within the `Click` event on the button control item.

I messed around with it after typing that last paragraph and I realized that the `$input.Text` property is populated correctly and is accessible in the `$global` scope. What I did was add `[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($input.Text)` at the very end of the script (after `$form.ShowDialog()`) and it showed exactly what I typed in the text box.

**So, why is it that I can't see the `$input` text box properties?** I haven't had this issue with some of the other WinForms apps I have built in Powershell.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: I was able to get the scope issue fixed. I just added `$global:` before the `$input.Text` property within the `Click` event for `$button`. That allowed it to access variables and objects within the global scope (obvious and narratively expositional but its for posterity). I'll edit the question and modify the given code so that others can just copy & paste and see the issue I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

`$input` is an automatic variable used in the context of the Powershell pipeline, which is why it was empty. Powershell populates it by itself, therefore overwriting anything you put in it. Rename `$input` to any other available name and it should work.

E.g.:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$box = New-Object Windows.Forms.TextBox
$box.Size = '100,20'
$box.Location = '10,20'

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Size = '100,20'
$button.Location = '10,60'
$button.Add_Click({
    [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($box.Text)
    Invoke-Expression ("man " + ($box.Text)) | Out-GridView
    })

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($box, $button))

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I did not know that. What I ended up doing was adding `$script:input.Text` in the MessageBox and it worked. Above, I used `$global:input.Text` but figured the `$script` scope was more appropriate. But I am still stuck on the problem on what I get when I click the `$button`. Try it out and you will see what I mean. GridView opens but it isn't formatted and prints literal table format text.